# Анонимные структуры

Tags: c

Вычитал на сайте это

> В некотором коде C широко распространено использование typedef вместе
>   с анонимными структурами.

Зачем пользоваться анонимными структурами вместе с typedef вместо простого объявления.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В С, в отличие от С++, слово `struct` приходится постоянно использовать с именем типа -

```
struct Pair { int a, b; };

struct Pair z;
```

Просто `Pair z;` будет не понято компилятором.

Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, можно дописать

```
typedef struct Pair mypair;
```

после чего

```
mypair z;
```

станет корректным объявлением. Получается, что само имя `Pair` de facto не используется нигде, кроме как при объявлении структуры и в `typedef`. Так не проще ли его вообще выкинуть и использовать `typedef` с анонимной структурой -

```
typedef struct { int a, b; } pair;

pair z;
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*